# COUNT or SUM of fields in MySql

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I have a table in my database which save up to 60 fields with a yes or a no. I am wanting to COUNT or get the SUM off all fields from the table WHERE any of the fields equal to 'yes';

I have tried the following but no luck:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'portraits';
```

This will return the column count but doesn't allow me to count the fields where they equal to 'yes'.

I am wondering is this easier to do in php? I am currently doing this in codeigniter and I don't know how to read the key/value as it is an object. Any ideas?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL  Look for "GROUP BY"

Comment: first line **save up to 60 fields with a yes or a no** and last line **WHERE any of the fields equal to 0**  when you are saving **yes/no** how can you check for **0**??

Comment: @DeepakSharma: It should be that, which is not in `yes` and `no`.

Comment: @Ravinder he can save whatever he want that is not the problem.. but when he already said **60 field with YES or NO** then how can you expect another values.. be logical yar..!!

Comment: @DeepakSharma: OK Logical: What if they are nullable and have NULLs in them?

Comment: yes null can be there.. I am arguing on **ZERO (0)** not on **NULL**.  Again its logical..!! now say  -

Comment: Yeah sorry my bad, I meant to say 'yes' not 0. Bad day already.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM information_schema.columns 
    WHERE table_name = 'portraits'
    AND (field1=0 OR field2=0 OR .... OR fieldN=0);
```

Comment: No. This is not what the OP is expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.... this simple query gonna work..... :)

```
SELECT
SUM(IF( information_schema = "YES", 1, 0) AS Yes,
SUM(IF( information_schema != "YES", 1, 0) AS No, 
FROM portraits
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS Yes, SUM(IF( information_schema != "YES", 1, 0) AS No, FROM portraits' at line 2

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT state, count(*) FROM information_schema.columns GROUP BY state;
```

Or in more complicated way :

```
SELECT y.total, n.total
  FROM (SELECT count(*) as total FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'portraits' AND state = 'yes') as y,
       (SELECT count(*) as total FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'portraits' AND state = 'no') as n
```